# When I try to run sonarqube for .net core in jenkins pipeline I'm getting misspelled error

Tags: asp.net-core, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

This is the error I facing right now:
`dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:ABPProjectDotnet /d:sonar.host.url=http://auditor.pro-inspector.net:9000 /d:sonar.login=******`

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-sonarscanner does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

This is my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps{
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Run Test') {
            tools {
                dotnetsdk 'dotnet-sdk-6.0'
            }
            steps {
                dir('TestProject') {
                    sh 'dotnet test'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Begin Sonar') {
            tools {
                dotnetsdk 'dotnet-sdk-6.0'
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube-8.9.9') {
                        sh 'dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"ABPProjectDotnet" /d:sonar.host.url="http://auditor.pro-inspector.net:9000"  /d:sonar.login="*****"'
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

here I set sonarqube-8.9.9 as sonarserver and I install globally sonarqube scanner tool in global tool but still I receiving this type of errorv when I try to run this in local which means try to run sonarqube in local it working perfectly fine.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I have some further questions; Is the user (running the pipeline/agent) allowed to do a global install? Are you sure a global install is survived from stage to stage? You can check the path via `echo "PATH is: ${env.PATH}"`

Comment: Also you leak credentials inside your `sh 'dotnet sonarscanner ... ` command. Please renew your credentials/token if at risk. I have summited an edit suggestion to your question, but the used login/credentials will remain in the (edit) history even if approved.